# Maximum Subgraph

Tags: python, algorithm, binding, graph-theory

I am currently looking at an implementation of the McGregor Maximum Subgraph in Python however I cannot seem to find an already implemented one.

I have found the algorithm implemented as part of the Boost C++ libraries however the Python bindings are missing.

This seem a bit odd?  Is this the right algorithm to use?  Are there any libraries out there which perform this task.

Comment: This site is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science. Migrating to stackoverflow...

Comment: It might be "the right algorithm to use" to solve your problem, but we don't know what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Suresh Please don't migrate questions to Stack Overflow which are off-topic here. If you are unfamiliar with the target site, vote to close instead of to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `networkx` package; I'm not sure if its `networkx.algorithms.mis.maximal_independent_set` is the same as the McGregor, but if you're working in networks, `networkx` is a useful package.

https://networkx.github.io/

Comment: In case somebody stumbles across this rather old question like I did: no, `maximal_independent_set` is most definitely NOT the same as the McGregor algorithm. As the OP stated, the latter is for finding the maximal common (i.e. isomorphic) subgraph of two graphs. `networkx` implements the "VF2" and "ISMAGS" algorithms that apparently can be used to find isomorphic subgraphs: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html?highlight=isomorphism#advanced-interfaces

Comment: After some further investigation, it seems that the VF2 subgraph methods in `networkx` don't solve the same problem as the McGregor algorithm. Given graphs A and B, McGregor tries to solve the problem of finding the largest graph C such that C is a subgraph of both A and B. The VF2 methods only allow you to find a subgraph of A that is isomorphic to B (or vice versa). Not quite the same thing... As far as I can tell, `networkx` has no built-in methods for solving the problem addressed by the McGregor algorithm. Please let me know if I'm wrong. I'd really like to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkX implementation of ISMAGS does include the maximal subgraph problem.
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.ismags.html

> In addition, this implementation also provides an interface to find the largest common induced subgraph [[2]](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.ismags.html#re111c1f21506-2) between any two graphs, again taking symmetry into account.